# Refetching query does not work after calling the useMutation hook in react

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-hooks, apollo, apollo-client

```
const [updateCompany, { data: muttatedCompany, error:updateCompanyError }] = useMutation(
        UPDATE_COMPANY_MUTATION, 
        { 
            errorPolicy: 'all',
            refetchQueries:[
              {query:COMPANYLIST}
            ],
         }
    );
```

`refetchQueries` doesn't work ... I spent a lot of time with it.

Comment: anyone have any idea about that how to call the refetchqueries after mutation done

Comment: `awaitRefetchQueries: true,` ?

Comment: i tried awaitRefetchQueries: true but it doesnt work

Comment: it works for me with query [operation] name as an arg (string, not object) ... no [query] request in network tab or UI/view not updated? different variables? it can be anything

Comment: after refetchqueries my UI part is not updated, in my case after mutation i will redirect to the other page,in that page only i want to expect the UI will update but its  not happens,once i refresh that page only it will update the UI

Comment: **if network request is made then refetchQueries works** ... [not] updating UI is another story, not related to this option/question - **ask a new question with ALL required/related details/code**

Comment: now i solved that issue by using refetch-policy: "network-only", it works for me

Comment: there is no `refetch-policy` option !?

Comment: i saw this option here https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/advanced-topics/

Comment: there is only `fetchPolicy` https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/core/ApolloClient/#functions not **RE**fetch-policy ... can be set globally or used per query, next to variables/other options